# I can't get the second part of my function to work, but there is no error shown when it's run

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function dropAndRetract1(e) {
  if(e.type = 'mouseover') {
    ul.eq(0).slideDown(1000).show();
  } else if(e.type = 'mouseout') {
    ul.eq(0).slideUp(1000).hide();
  }
}

th.eq(0).on('mouseover mouseout', dropAndRetract1);
```

Comment: One equals `=` is for assignment, you can use `===` (or `==`) for comparison

Answer (score 0):

```
function dropAndRetract1(e) {
  if(e.type == 'mouseover') {
    ul.eq(0).slideDown(1000).show();
  } else if(e.type == 'mouseout') {
    ul.eq(0).slideUp(1000).hide();
  }
}

th.eq(0).on('mouseover mouseout', dropAndRetract1);
```

Error is not shown because you are assigning the value instead of comparing in if condition. Use "==" or "===" for comparison.